# Dynamically ViewPager flow of pages

Tags: android, android-viewpager

I've used [ViewPager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/view/ViewPager.html) to let the user flip left and right to navigate among pages of a given activity.

Is it possible to programatically control the flow of pages of the ViewPager?

For exemple:
If the user didn't fill a given EditText on the current page, I don't want him to be able to navigate to the next one.

Another case: If the user is currently on page 1 and if hi filled a given EditText with a specific value and the user flip right to left, I want him to go straight to the 5th page instead of the 2nd one.

Answer (score 0):

By "flipping" you mean dragging with a finger or just using the ViewPager for animation?

If it's the former, you'll have to dynamically edit the children of the ViewPager to get the effect you want. You can override `onInterceptTouchEvent()` to block touch events until a page is completed.

However, I recommend disabling finger-dragging in the ViewPager (perhaps using `onInterceptTouchEvent()`) and then using `setCurrentItem(4, true)` to show the animation and navigate to a specific page. The logic you need can be implemented using buttons which will call `setCurrentItem(4, true)`. For example, you can have a "Next->" button that is grayed out unless the form is completely completed. That will be more intuitive then the first option anyway.

Edit: 4 is just whatever child index you want to switch to.